# new FileOutputStream cause a Jhipster Application restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext, jhipster, fileoutputstream

I've searched a lot before asking.  I've created a Jhipster microservice application (v 3.12), and I use the iText library to generate my own PDF based on a template.

I've tested the `GeneratePdfFromPdfTemplate class` in another project (not Spring Boot, but a simple maven project) and it works great; but when I run it in my JHipster project the new `FileOutputStream` instruction cause the problem:

public static void generatePdf(String src, String dest, String codiceAvviso) {

```
    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fos);
        PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(1); 
        ...
```

When I debug it, the new FileOutputStream(dest); force to restart my application causing this log:

```
2017-04-05 14:15:50.160  INFO 12432 --- [       Thread-1] c.c.xenia.config.CacheConfiguration      : Closing Cache Manager
2017-04-05 14:15:50.165 DEBUG 12432 --- [       Thread-1] c.e.c.E.consoft.xenia.domain.Authority   : Close successful.
2017-04-05 14:15:50.166 DEBUG 12432 --- [       Thread-1] c.e.c.E.c.x.d.User.persistentTokens      : Close successful.
2017-04-05 14:15:50.168 DEBUG 12432 --- [       Thread-1] .E.c.x.d.p.w.p.w.I.datiSingoloVersamento : Close successful.
2017-04-05 14:15:50.169 DEBUG 12432 --- [       Thread-1] c.e.c.E.c.x.d.p.w.p.w.InviaCarrPosOutput : Close successful.
2017-04-05 14:15:50.171 DEBUG 12432 --- [       Thread-1] .d.p.w.g.w.InserimentoPosizioneInputType : Close successful.
2017-04-05 14:15:50.172 DEBUG 12432 --- [       Thread-1] c.e.c.E.c.xenia.domain.PlacementTest     : Close successful.
```

the src and dest string are respectively:
src:

> C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Xenia\src\main\resources\templateAgid.pdf

dest:

> C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Xenia\src\main\resources\Avviso_Pagamento_001385698469599575.pdf

Comment: You shouldn't be creating files in those locations as that is the classpath next to that it will likely fail in y9our real production environment... Write tom some other path like `/tmp` or `java.io.tmpdir`...

Comment: Yes and the application restarts because your pom.xml has sprinb boot dev tools which watches source path for changes and reloading your app.